# HTML navigation bar problems

Tags: html, css

So when I load my page I have a navigation bar but for some reason my padding between my ul's are different, and i think it is because the borders, and my `#nav` is centered correctly but my ul's aren't really centered as it has to be. Also on my hover the entire navigation goes with it, and i only need 1 li to go down.

see image: [image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2q21jlw.jpg]

html code:

```css
    body {
      background: url(../images/wallpaper.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    /*De navigatie bar*/

    #nav {
      width: 80%;
      height: 50px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;

    }

    #nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 45px;
      width: 24%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #nav ul li {
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      opacity: 0.3;
      background-color: #A7B5BF;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
    }

    #nav ul:first-child li {
      border-left: 2px solid black;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 50;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Sans-serif, Verdana;
    }

    #nav ul li:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      margin-top: 2px;
    }

    /*einde navigatie bar*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
  <title>website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a>
      </li>
      <!--<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     </ul> -->
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Galary</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ToS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have the `ul` elements with a single `li`? Are you intending on having sub menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the odd hover behaviour is this section:

```
#nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

By adding a margin to the `li`, you are forcing up the `ul`, which is pushing everything down. You can easily fix this by changing the above to:

```
#nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position:relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

---

A much simpler way to achieve this is to use a simpler list structure:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Galary</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ToS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then you can use the [`display:table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) rule to easily set up the list items without having to resort to floats (which can get messy quickly), like so:

```
#nav ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}
```

There is a [complete JSfiddle here which should give you an idea of how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/74a0mv9o/).

Comment: This works thnx! but now my borders are messed up , i just want 2px each side 1 time. and make it center all

Comment: @user2855957 Well as people have state, there are some issues with your HTML markup that might help fix that. Does your markup need to be structured that way?

Comment: not really, i'm just testing things out but it's only the space between the ul's that is a problem, and i'm just not sure if it's all about the borders or the Width i used

Comment: I've given you an alternate structure with some suggestions for easier  ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clean up your code a little bit. you dont need all those ul elements...just one should suffice. here is the code snippet for you.. hopefully this helps you

```css
#nav{
    /*padd en marge mag weg*/
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    width: 100%%;  /* changed this so that the nav bar takes up the entire width specified */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width:25%; /* since you have 4 total nav items i divided the total width by 4 */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* add this since you have used border */
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: #A7B5BF;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
#nav ul li:first-child{
    border-left: 2px solid black; /* re arranged this so that the first child pseudo is given to the li element */
}
#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Sans-serif, Verdana;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
/*einde navigatie bar*/
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ToS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="footer"><p></p></div>
```

Comment: this just puts it under each other :/

Answer (score -1):

This is how your menu structure should be.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ToS</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: How does changing the HTML fix the CSS behaviour?